# Trying to show that $e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}1/k!$ goes to $0$ faster than $n!$ goes to infinity as $n\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

This have been asked before but I think people misunderstood my question.

For a better notation:
$e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}1/k! = e - \sum^n$ .

Having the following inequality:

$0 < n!(e-\sum^n) <1/n \tag{1}$

we can apply the squeeze theorem to show that $n!(e-\sum^n)$ goes to zero as $n$  goes to infinity.

If $n!(e-\sum^n)$ goes to zero when $n \to \infty$ this means that $\sum^n$ converges so quickly to $e$ that $(e-\sum^n)$ goes to $0$ faster than $n!$ goes to infinity as $n \to \infty$.

Is possible to show this without relying on $(1)\:?$

Comment: What is the definition of $a_n\to 0$ going faster than $b_n\to\infty$? Would it be $\lim a_nb_n=0$?

Comment: The Taylor remainder theorem for $e^x$ seems like a good bet. I believe the upper bound it gives you is $\frac{e}{n+1}$: good enough to prove your result, but not quite as good as (1)...

Comment: It is very easy to prove 1). Why should you avoid it? If you want a simple proof of 1) please let me know.

Comment: You are in fact asking to show $$\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\dfrac{n!}{k!}<1.$$

Comment: I don't see anything labelled as "$(1)$" .

Answer (score 2):

To prove (1):
$$
n!(e-\sum^n)=n!\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\ldots\right)=\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\ldots\\ \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)} +\ldots\\
=\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3} +\ldots\\
=\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n}.
$$